# How to use Location finder class in an Activity.

Tags: java, android, geolocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a)

I am new in android.

I just want to know how can i use the MyLocation class in my Activity which is posted on this link

[What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a/3145655#3145655)

Thank u so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just call it in your activity :

```
MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
```

Comment: thank u so much , but can u please elaborate ? i am not getting how to do this !

Answer (score 0):

```
MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
private void locationClick() {
    myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult));
}

public LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
    @Override
    public void gotLocation(final Location location){
        //Got the location!
        });
    }
};
```

That code is verbatim from the answer you linked. Just create `MyLocation` and pass in a `LocationResult` callback handler. `gotLocation()` will be called with a [`Location`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html). You can get latitude and longitude from there.

Comment: But still i am not getting how to get latitude and longitude from there. Can u please elaborate ?

Comment: hey there is one more My Location class which is posted by wormhit on the same post. Can u please tell me how to use this class in an activity ?

Comment: Did you even try to read the documentation? `Location` has a `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()`. More work on basic Java is probably a necessary first step, but if you want to use wormhit's code, then read and over and try it. Post a different question if you really can't get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.i read the documentation very well and i know about the methods getLongitude() and getLatitude(). The thing that i was not getting is how the location is transferring from myLocation class to my own Activity but now i got it. But still i am not able to understand the wormhit's code can u please explain how can i use it. Thank u so much.